# ¿Cómo realizar una condición para no repetir registros en una base de SQLite?

Tags: mysql, android, base-de-datos, sqlite

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de Android que necesita una base de datos la cual le pide su código de barras de credencial de los alumnos a través del escanea por la cámara  de su teléfono o, que sean introducidos por ellos en un edit text, junto con sus nombres ,apellidos, etc. (estos enviados a una tabla en mi base de datos). Aquí necesito la condicion que les impida registrarse si es que el codebar introducido ya existe en otro registro.
Código de Base de datos SQLite y las 2 tablas:
package

com.example.application;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context,String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase AdminRoom) {
       AdminRoom.execSQL("create table alumnos(codebar text primary key, nombres text, apellidos text,semestre int, grupo text, especialidad text)");
        AdminRoom.execSQL("create table capturar(codebar text primary key, sala int, hora_inicial text,hora_termino text, grupo text, especialidad text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Codigo de el registro de datos de los alumnos:

```
package com.example.application;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;


public class Registrar extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    String[] Turnos = new String[] {"Matutino", "Vespertino"};
  EditText etCodigo, Name, Apel, Sem, Grup,Espe;
  Button btnEscanaer;
  Spinner turno;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrar);
        turno = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Turnos);
        turno.setAdapter(adapter);

        Name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        String Names=Name.getText().toString();
        Apel=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Apel);
        String Apell=Apel.getText().toString();
        Sem=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Sem);
        String Seme=Sem.getText().toString();
        Grup=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Grup);
        String Grupo=Grup.getText().toString();
        Espe=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Espe);
        String Espec=Espe.getText().toString();
        etCodigo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCodigos);
        btnEscanaer=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEscaner);
        btnEscanaer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                escaner();
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Registrar();
            }

        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.registrar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_inicio) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Registrar.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_enter) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Registrar.this, Entrar.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_register) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Registrar.this, Ayuda.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_report) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Registrar.this, Reporte.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }
    public void Registrar(){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase AdminRoom = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String codebar = etCodigo.getText().toString();
        String nombres = Name.getText().toString();
        String apellidos = Apel.getText().toString();
        String semestre = Sem.getText().toString();
        String grupo = Grup.getText().toString();
        String turnos = turno.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String especialidad = Espe.getText().toString();

        if(!codebar.isEmpty() || !nombres.isEmpty() || !apellidos.isEmpty() || !semestre.isEmpty() || !grupo.isEmpty() || !especialidad.isEmpty()){
            ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
            registro.put("codebar",codebar);
            registro.put("nombres",nombres);
            registro.put("apellidos",apellidos);
            registro.put("semestre",semestre);
            registro.put("grupo",grupo);
            registro.put("turnos",turnos);
            registro.put("especialidad",especialidad);

            AdminRoom.insert("alumnos", null, registro);

            AdminRoom.close();
            etCodigo.setText("");
            Name.setText("");
            Apel.setText("");
            Sem.setText("");
            Grup.setText("");
            Espe.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(this, "Envio Exitoso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            MostrarAlertDialog2();
        }

    }
    public void MostrarAlertDialog2() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder2.setTitle("ATENCION");
        builder2.setMessage("Rellena los campos en blanco para poder registrarte. (Asegurate que la informacion introducida sea correcta).");
        builder2.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        builder2.create();
        builder2.show();

    }
    public void escaner(){
        IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);

        intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
        intent.setCameraId(0);
        intent.setBeepEnabled(false);
        intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        intent.initiateScan();
        intent.setOrientationLocked(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if( result != null){
           if(result.getContents() == null){
               Toast.makeText(this,"Escaneo Cancelado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }else{
               etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString());
               String Codigo=etCodigo.getText().toString();
           }

        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        }
    }
}
```

Se que es demasiado extenso pero agradecería mucho su ayuda. :)

Comment: no desarrollo para movil... pero la teoria es que primero verifiques si y existe ese codigo con SELECT FROM y guardes ese resultado y luego preguntes si te trajo registros, si trae registros entonces mandas un mensaje de que ya existe ese codigo y le des un RETURN o la instruccion que manejes para interrumpir el avance del programa..... en youtube hay muchos cursos de SQL, todas las bases de datos SQL tienen un ESTANDAR para las operaciones de consulta, agregar, actualizar y eliminar (select, insert, update, delete) asi que cualquier curso basico de SQL de SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc. te va

Comment: ese es el problema nose cual es el codigo que me realiza esto pero se que debe de existir, intente con algo como esto: Cursor fila = AdminRoom.rawQuery
                ("SELECT codebar FROM alumnos Where codebar ="+codebar, null);
        if(fila.moveToFirst()){
            txtt=1;
        }else {txtt=0;}                             Pero no funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente no necesitas validar primero, ya que la columna `codebar` al ser llave primaria será protegida de duplicados por SQLite y arrojará un error.

Simplemente usa `AdminRoom.insertOrThrow` en lugar de `AdminRoom.insert` y maneja en un `catch` la excepción cuando ocurra.

```
try{
   AdminRoom.insertOrThrow("alumnos", null, registro);
}catch(SQLException e){
   // Manejo de excepcion, Ej. Mostrar diálogo
}
```

Comment: Perdon pero el catch donde lo impementaria? , nunca eh utilizado el try...catch. (Perdona mi ignorancia) .

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo de *try-catch* a la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Te agradesco por ayudarme , podrias ayudarme en la respuesta de mi otra pregunta?... esta relacionado con esta pero es un problema un poco diferente... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267076/como-realizar-una-condici%C3%B3n-de-un-registro-introducido-sea-el-mismo-que-el-de-ot