# ¿Cómo realizar una condición de un registro introducido sea el mismo que el de otra tabla?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy aquí por la posibilidad de ayuda en la información de cómo realizar una condición que consiste en que un usuario introduzca un código y si el código es el mismo que contiene otra tabla en el cual anteriormente se registró, se registraran los datos aparte del código y si no es el mismo le mostrará un mensaje que este usuario es inexistente.

Este es el código de la base de datos:

```
package com.example.application;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context,String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase AdminRoom) {
        AdminRoom.execSQL("create table alumnos(codebar text primary key unique, nombres text, apellidos text,semestre text, grupo text, turnos text, especialidad text)");
        AdminRoom.execSQL("create table capturar(codebar text, salas text, hora_inicial text, hora_termino text, FOREIGN KEY(codebar) REFERENCES alumnos(codebar) )");
        AdminRoom.execSQL("create table reportes(reporte TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase AdminRoom, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Formulario:

```
package com.example.application;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class Entrar extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    int txt;
    String[] TimeInicio = new String[] {"7:00 AM", "8:00 AM","9:00 AM","10:00 AM","11:00 AM","12:00 AM","1:00 PM","2:00 PM","3:00 PM","4:00 PM","5:00 PM","6:00 PM","7:00 PM","8:00 PM"};
    String[] TimeTermino = new String[] {"8:00 AM","9:00 AM","10:00 AM","11:00 AM","12:00 AM","1:00 PM","2:00 PM","3:00 PM","4:00 PM","5:00 PM","6:00 PM","7:00 PM","8:00 PM","9:00 PM"};
    String[] Salas = new String[] {"Sala 1","Sala 2","Sala 3","Sala 4"};
    EditText etCods;
    Button btnEscanaers;
    Spinner timei, timet, sala;
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrar);
        timei = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnertmi);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TimeInicio);
        timei.setAdapter(adapter);

        timet = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnertmt);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TimeTermino);
        timet.setAdapter(adapter2);
        sala = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnersala);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Salas);
        sala.setAdapter(adapters);
        etCods=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCo);
        btnEscanaers=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btsn);
        btnEscanaers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             escaners();
            }

        });


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Buscar();
        }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.entrar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_inicio) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Entrar.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_enter) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_register) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Entrar.this, Registrar.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Entrar.this, Ayuda.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_report) {
            Intent enter = new Intent(Entrar.this, Reporte.class);
            startActivity(enter);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    public void Buscar(){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"administracion",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase AdminRoom = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        AdminRoom.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");

        String codebar = etCods.getText().toString();
        String salas = sala.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String hora_inicial = timei.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String hora_termino = timet.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(!codebar.isEmpty()){

            ContentValues capturars = new ContentValues();
            capturars.put("codebar",codebar);
            capturars.put("salas",salas);
            capturars.put("hora_inicial",hora_inicial);
            capturars.put("hora_termino",hora_termino);
            try {
                AdminRoom.insertOrThrow("capturar", null, capturars);
                AdminRoom.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Captura de Entrada Exitosa Exitosa. Ya puedes cerrar la aplicacion si lo deseas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent enter = new Intent(Entrar.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(enter);
            }catch (Exception e2){
                MostrarAlertDialogE();
            }
             etCods.setText("");
        }else {
            MostrarAlertDialog();}
    }
    public void MostrarAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("ATENCION");
        builder.setMessage("Rellena los campos en blanco para poder registrar tu entrada (Revisa que la informacion introducida sea correcta).");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        builder.create();
        builder.show();

    }
    public void MostrarAlertDialogE() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("ATENCION");
        builder.setMessage("El usuario con este codigo no exite,es necesario registrarlo para capturar la entrada.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        builder.create();
        builder.show();

    }
    public void escaners(){
        IntentIntegrator intent = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);

        intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
        intent.setCameraId(0);
        intent.setBeepEnabled(false);
        intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        intent.initiateScan();
        intent.setOrientationLocked(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if( result != null){
            if(result.getContents() == null){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Escaneo Cancelado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                etCods.setText(result.getContents().toString());
            }

        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        }

    }
}
```

Eh intentado realizar la condición pero no consigo tener el resultado esperado.Espero que puedan ayudarme y de antemano, Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El concepto que te puede ayudar es el de *Integridad referencial*, el cual aplicas en una base de datos mediante una *llave foránea* desde la columna dependiente hacia la tabla *padre ó maestra*.

Simplemente al crear la tabla haz:

```
        AdminRoom.execSQL("create table capturar(codebar text, salas text, hora_inicial text, hora_termino text, FOREIGN KEY(codebar) REFERENCES alumnos(codebar) )");
```

Para que la FK funcione hay que habilitarlas agregando al `SQLOpenHelper`:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```

Con esto, al intentar insertar un registro en `capturar` cuyo `codebar` no exista en `alumnos` SQLite arrojará una excepción.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94180/discussion-on-answer-by-sal-como-realizar-una-condicion-de-un-registro-introduc).